CiviCRM SearchKit or Drupal Views to create exportable data that includes Grand Total Rows
I'm new to CiviCRM and Drupal and I'm trying to create a report for my end users which will contain the activities they have completed each month and will total some of the data captured in the activity, e.g. number of hours.
I have managed to create a report within SearchKit that shows this information with the Grand Total at the bottom of the report. However when trying to export this, either in a Excel or PDF format, the Grand Total row is excluded.
I'm trying to understand if it is possible to also export the Grand Total line within the main export or whether I would need to create the report via a Drupal view instead to achieve this combined functionality.
Has anyone done this before and can provide a method or comment on which method is best?
Thanks!
For reference I am using CiviCRM v5.77.0 and Drupal v10.3.3

Hi Jess, welcome to StackExchange. This is a good question. I'm not sure if this is possible but have shared on chat to see if anyone else has found a solution.

Unfortunately this isn't currently possible in SearchKit though this may be added as a feature in future.
One option would be to edit the exported spreadsheet to add the total row manually. I'm not sure if that would fit with your workflow though.
